# Make Python Script to read modify and write TSV file efficient

Tags: python, csv

I have a file of size 800MB that I would like to iterate through and find which `taxonID` belongs to which kingdom. Each row has a `parentNameUsageID` which points to its next parent. I recurse until I find next parent whose `taxonRank` is `kingdom`. The file over 2M records which makes it resource intensive. I have a working script that does what I need but I create a dictionary so I can easily access the attributes and once the whole dictionary is updated with the new kingdom field, I write it to a file. Is there is a better way to do it, like read -> update -> write each row to a new file without waiting for the whole thing to finish?

Also, Can we do it in a better way so it doesnot use as much resources and goes faster than 2 rows in a mins (that's the current speed)? Each recursion opens the file again. If I dont, it only iterates through part of the file and not the whole file.

Sample Data file cab be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nfF7dRcIcKxWyJgbYVwEiaq6hMxvIPGD/view?usp=sharing) - 840 MB

Code:

```
import csv
import time
import io

file_name = "Taxon.tsv"
def getKingdomName(parentID):
    with open(file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        tfr = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="\t")
        for t in tfr:
            if t["dwc:taxonID"] == parentID:
                # print("Found", t["dwc:taxonID"])
                if t["dwc:taxonRank"] == 'kingdom':
                    # print("kingdom name: ", t["dwc:scientificName"])
                    return t["dwc:scientificName"]
                else:
                    # print("No kingdom match. Calling getKingdomName with", t["dwc:parentNameUsageID"])
                    return getKingdomName(t["dwc:parentNameUsageID"])
            else:
                pass


with open(file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    taxon_file = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="\t")
    new_taxon_file = None
    print("start:", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
    for line in taxon_file:
        # print(line)
        kingdomName = getKingdomName(line["dwc:parentNameUsageID"])
        line["dwc:kingdom"] = kingdomName
        print(line)

    memory_file = io.StringIO()
    with open('Taxon-out.tsv', "w", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as output:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=taxon_file.fieldnames, delimiter="\t")
        for row in taxon_file:
            writer.writerow(row)

    print("end:", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
``
```

Comment: use `file.seek(0)` to move to the beginning of file without opening again.

Comment: `840MB` is not big file and you could read all to memory. And this should make code faster. You could also use `pandas.DataFrame` to simpler search again - and `pandas` uses code created in `C/C++` so it may work faster.

Comment: using file.seek(0) has the same speed as opening a new file. I will use pandas and see if it gets any faster. I think it is the comparing of IDs that is slower

Comment: it is slow because you read again from file - if you would read it only once and keep all in memory then it could be faster. Reading and writing always was slow and systems/programs try to keep data in memory (ie. system uses buffers to keep data in memory before it saves all on disk, or it use buffer to read bigger part at once and later send data to program from buffer)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to tackle this issue of slow processing using the below code. The performance suffers with pandas if I iterate through each row. The below code does not iterate through the rows. It just looks up the row by the index column using the ID `df.loc("dwc:taxonID")`. This improves performance from 2 rows per min to 1000 rows per second.

@furas: thanks for your help in comments.

I hope this helps someone trying to accomplish the same thing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dtypes = {
    'dwc:parentNameUsageID': str,
    'dwc:acceptedNameUsageID': str,
    'dwc:originalNameUsageID': str,
    'dwc:datasetID': str,
    'dwc:taxonomicStatus': str,
    'dwc:taxonRank': str,
    'dwc:scientificName': str,
    'gbif:genericName': str,
    'dwc:specificEpithet': str,
    'dwc:infraspecificEpithet': str,
    'dwc:nameAccordingTo': str,
    'dwc:namePublishedIn': str,
    'dwc:nomenclaturalStatus': str,
    'dwc:nomenclaturalCode': str,
    'dwc:taxonRemarks': str,
    'dcterms:references': str
}

taxon_fp = 'Taxon.tsv' # 'taxon-small.tsv' 'Taxon.tsv'
out_file = 'Taxon-out.tsv'  # 'taxon-small-out.tsv' 'Taxon-out.tsv'
df = pd.read_csv(taxon_fp, sep="\t", encoding="utf-8", index_col="dwc:taxonID", na_filter=False)

for col, dtype in dtypes.items():
    df[col] = df[col].astype(dtype)

kingdom_list = []
def getKingdomName(taxonID):
    row = df.loc[taxonID]
    if row["dwc:taxonRank"] == "kingdom":
        return row["dwc:scientificName"]
    elif row["dwc:parentNameUsageID"] == '':
        if row["dwc:acceptedNameUsageID"] == '':
            return ''
        else:
            return getKingdomName(row["dwc:acceptedNameUsageID"])
    else:
        return getKingdomName(row["dwc:parentNameUsageID"])

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["dwc:taxonRank"] == 'kingdom':
        kingdomName = row["dwc:scientificName"]
    else:
        kingdomName = getKingdomName(i)
    kingdom_list.append(kingdomName)
df['dwc:kingdom'] = kingdom_list
new_columns = []
for item in df.columns:
    new_columns.append(item.replace('dwc:', '').replace('gbif:', '').replace('dcterms:', ''))
df.columns = new_columns
df.index.name = 'taxonID'
df.to_csv(out_file, sep="\t")
```